# Android twitter4j - how to share remote image?

Tags: android, image, twitter, twitter4j

I have successfully set up twitter4j and can now post text updates and also upload local media from the device to twitter. But what I really need to do is share **remote** images from the web - e.g., `http://example.com/image.png`.

When I execute this code...

`StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate("Hello Twitter");
String imageUrl = "http://example.com/image.png";
File file = new File(imageUrl);
statusUpdate.setMedia(file);
twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);`

...it looks like twitter4j tries to treat the url as local because it appears to put a `/` in front of it, and then throws an exception saying...
`/http://example.com/image.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

How to solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found there is another `setMedia()` method that accepts an inputstream as one of it's parameters. This inputstream can be linked to a remote image, like this...

```
StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate("Hello Twitter");
String imageUrl = "http://example.com/image.png";
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
statusUpdate.setMedia("image.png", in);
twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
//might be a good idea to close the inputstream in a finally block
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, the workaround i found was to download the image to your phone and then post it on twitter using the following code:

```
StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(String status);
File file = new File(imageFilePath);
status.setMedia(file);
mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is a good solution to do that. I have worked out the correct solution. I will post it as an answer shortly...

Comment: That would be good, i would also like to know a better way to do that :)

Comment: See my answer, below. Works a treat!

Comment: That's Mr Dude to you! No worries - hope it helps you too.